# Listen device orientation change when orientation is locked

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, mediarecorder, device-orientation

I created camera activity and fixed its orientation to portrait from manifest.

```
  <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.CameraActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           >
```

As I'm taking video by mediarecorder I need to understand orientation to save video in correct position.

mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orentation);

I'm getting orientation from this function

```
  public int setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                                            int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
                new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        } else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setRotation(result);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
        return result;
    }
```

When orientation not fixed from manifest this method works fine, but as I need to fix orientation my videos saving only in portrait state.

Help me to determine landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue by programmatically change orientation of activity in video mode:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

just detect the camera mode (image/video) and change orientation accordingly